# ROS communication from PC to RaspberryPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iptables, ros, netcat

I have a communication problem from my PC to RaspberryPi using ROS, as I cannot send messages from PC to Rasp, but vice-versa works. I do not understand where is the problem.

I am running ros-kinetic on my PC and RaspberryPi, and implemented a ros_pub and ros_sub packages on both machines. I wanted to publish sensor message topic using ros_pub package on PC, and subscribe that sensor message topic using ros_sub package on RaspberryPi.

Master URI is running on RaspberryPi.

publisher.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from ros_msgs.msg import SensorInformation

def publisher():
    rospy.init_node('publisher')
    pub = rospy.Publisher('message_topic', SensorInformation, queue_size=1)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)

    sensor = SensorInformation()
    sensor.data.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    sensor.data.header.frame_id = "Ultrasonic Sensor Frame"
    sensor.data.radiation_type=sensor.data.ULTRASOUND
    #sensor.data.field_of_view = 0.5
    sensor.data.range = 23.10
    #sensor.data.min_range = 0.002
    #sensor.data.max_range= 2.00
    #sensor.part_number = 14320
    #sensor.manufacturer_name= "Sri"

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pub.publish(sensor)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        publisher()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

subscriber.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from ros_msgs.msg import SensorInformation

def subCallback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(data.data.range)

def subscriber():
    rospy.init_node('subscriber')
    rospy.Subscriber('message_topic', SensorInformation, subCallback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        subscriber()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

SensorInformation.msg

```
sensor_msgs/Range data
string manufacturer_name
uint32 part_number
```

PC's .bashrc

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.81:11311/
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.102
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.102
```

RaspPi's .bashrc

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.81:11311/
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.81
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.81
```

when I ran rosrun ros_pub publisher.py on PC and tested rostopic echo /message_topic, whether topic is being published on the same machine. It's publishing the message with some data

and ran rosrun ros_sub subscriber.py on RaspberryPi, i could not receive the message data and tested rostopic echo /message_topic if I could see any message data, and there is no data.

Here is the result, when I run rosnode info /publisher

```
rosnode info /publisher 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/publisher]
Publications: 
 * /message_topic [std_msgs/String]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: None

Services: 
 * /publisher/get_loggers
 * /publisher/set_logger_level


contacting node http://192.168.1.102:44631/ ...
ERROR: Communication with node[http://192.168.1.102:44631/] failed!
```

However, the vice-versa works, i.e., publisher as RaspberryPi and Subscriber as PC.

where could the problem lies? and what is the solution?

Also,using rospy_tutorials I have tried to run talker.py on PC and listener.py on RaspberryPi, I could not get message on RaspberryPi.

In addition, I have a basic problem which is described below:
on PC

```
netcat -l 1234
```

on RaspPi

```
netcat 192.168.1.102 1234
```

This fetches no result, at least no error.

I then ran the below which give no route to host,

```
netcat -nvz -w 1 192.168.1.102 1234
netcat: connect to 192.168.1.102 port 1234 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

Comment: Are you use that your PC is connected correctly with the master?

Comment: It is connected correctly, otherwise when I run rostopic echo from PC it should not ran be successully, I would have got error message "Unable to communicate to Master" or something, but I am getting result on PC

Comment: Try to use `rostopic pub` on the terminal to publish something to the direction you want (that is not working) and try to `rostopic echo` on the other end.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant "rostopic pub", why it publishes something??

Comment: `rostopic pub` is a command utility to publish a topic. It takes several other arguments, but is an efficient way to test if two machines can talk with each other.

Comment: Oh I did not know about that, I tried that but no luck, I could not receive the other side of machine/raspberryPi

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the .bashrc of both machines?

Comment: Also, when you are using the rostopic pub command try to publish a message of type string. This should tell us if the problem is related with your custom msg.

Comment: @Rafael I edited. And yeah I have tried only that when you said about rostopic pub cmd utlity. It wasn't working.

Comment: ROS_HOSTNAME should be master’s IP address! Try this. Edit your computers bashrc, source it and try again.

Comment: @Rafael I have created before simple packages with simple message topics 
 for publisher and subscriber using String. I tried rostopic pub on these, but it wasn't working.

Comment: Can you try what I suggested about the ROS_HOSTNAME? To see if this is related? I have the impression that the IP there should be master’s IP.

Comment: @Rafael I modified the changes and tried on new terminal but no result. i cannot see the message on RaspPi. (On the other hand, vice-versa works as before)

Comment: Also I tried what's in this link suggested https://answers.ros.org/question/272065/specification-of-ros_master_uri-and-ros_hostname/. Result is no change. I cannot see the message. Please let me know if you ahve any other suggestions

Comment: That is very weird... I can only suspect some firewall on one of the computers?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem what this guy was facing in https://answers.ros.org/question/304980/ros-with-raspberry-pi-and-pc/. I tried what is said, but no result or I do not understand what must .bashrc on PC

Comment: He is basically saying that he left the ROS_IP empty. Just unset this?

Comment: I just left blank for ROS_IP on RaspPi and the result was no change.. I will try to leave ROS_IP black on PC too, and check the result...

Comment: @Rafael also the result has no change, do you have any idea of why I am getting the error when I run rosnode info /publisher on raspPi?? (see updated post)

Comment: Try to ping each other. `ping 192.168.1.102` from pi and `ping 192.168.1.81` from pc see if they are reachable over the network.

Comment: I tried that several times, it is working, also vice-versa! but when I use netcat -l 1234 on PC and netcat 192.168.1.102 1234 on raspPi, it does not work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to your ROS master network configuration for ROS.

Since you can ping the master but a subscriber can't subscribe to a topic, this shows that probably the master computer (in your case RaspberryPi) don't accept remote connections but only local. To verify this hypothesis, try to run both the publisher and the subscriber on your RaspberryPi, you should get the desired result. If this is true, then, configure the following on ROS master:

```
export ROS_IP=0.0.0.0
```

This is to listen to any interface.

Try if this fixes the problem, otherwise, try the following:

Add the following to your PC's `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.1.81 PUT_HOSTNAME_OF_RASPBERRYPI_HERE
```

Comment: No, the two solutions you provided did not resolve the problem. I have the same basic problem netcat -l 1234 on PC and netcat raspberrypi 1234, does not work. However, the vice-versa works!

Answer (score 1):

So, after a thorough understanding of my problem and gathering knowledge on linux networking/configuration, I realized the problem lies in firewall configuration of my PC/Linux, it is blocking the access.

Basically, iptables is a default firewall on Linux. I cleared the iptables rules on my PC by running the following commands

```
# iptables -F
# iptables -X
# iptables -t nat -F
# iptables -t nat -X
# iptables -t mangle -F
# iptables -t mangle -X
```

And that works! :D

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/no-route-to-host-error-and-solution.html

Comment: That's very strange. Usually when I configure a new machine with ROS I don't have such issues. But well done for figuring this out.

Comment: I had seen one computer having similar issues and never quite figured our the root cause.  We ended up having to nuke the system.

Comment: Firewall configuration of Linux machine is not related to ROS.. when I saw iptables, there was already a lot (including docker related which was automatically) configured, and it’s been over 3 months I am using that OS, and I do not know when that configuration has been changed or don’t know if that firewall configuration packed with that OS Ubuntu 18.04. If there is such problems occur I suggest start analysis of the problem from Firewall configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem! I had been trying so many different things and everything was due to my Ubuntu 18.04 firewall! It was blocking the connection, even though  I was able to ping and rostopic and rosnode lists seemed fine!
However, this way of clearing the iptables rules given by Srivardhan Cholkar
wasn't working for me, it was turning off my Internet connection...

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
```

I solved it by running:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

And worked!

Source: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-firewall-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux